# Select/Filter specific rows in jTable

Tags: java, jtable

My Task is to develop a Software which is measuring times of different participants.

Following problem:

each participant has 2 chances to give his/her best and the software has to select the best 32/16/.. times for the next round

The times are saved in a MySql DB, selected with Hibernate and saved in a Datatable using own Tablemodel (RunTableModel extends DefaultTableModel)

for example:

```
Participant | Time  
------------|------   
Tina        | 10:15  
Tina        | 10:20  
Carl        | 11:00  
Carl        | 10:17  
Charlie     | 12:01  
Charlie     | 11:50
```

My question now is how to filter this results in a jTable.
-> One option would probably be to do this by selection from the Database (Hibernate HQL) but therefore I have to reload always from DB

Is there a possability to do this with filters?

Result should look like this:

```
Participant | Time  
------------|------  
Tina        | 10:15  
Carl        | 10:17  
Charlie     | 11:50
```